# Filtering by date in GORM

Tags: database, orm, go, go-gorm

I'm using [GORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) to access the records in my database. Now I want to retrieve all records that are not deleted which means, that the attribute DeletedAt must be NULL.

I tried the following command chains with [`WHERE()`](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#query-with-where-plain-sql), but they returned no results.

```
users := []*models.User{}
db.Where("deleted_at", nil).Find(&users)
```

and

```
db.Where("deleted_at", "NULL").Find(&users)
```

My database model is defined by the following structs:

```
type Model struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `sql:"size:32; not null; unique"`
    Password string `sql:"not null"`
    Locale   string `sql:"not null"`
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all RDBMS, the SQL standard mandates that a condition involving a comparison with a NULL value is always false. The following query therefore always returns an empty result:

```
select * from XXX where deleted_at = NULL
```

If you want to search for NULL values, you are supposed to write:

```
select * from XXX where deleted_at is null
```

I think you can fix the issue by making sure GORM generates the correct query. For instance, this should work (untested):

```
db.Where("deleted_at is null").Find(&users)
```